# Procurar qual o tamanho da maior sequência de # numa matriz. JAVA

Tags: java, matriz

Sou nova em Java e encontrei este problema:

> Dada uma matriz de caracteres ('.' ou '#'), a sua tarefa é indicar o
>   tamanho do maior segmento contíguo (horizontal ou vertical) de
>   caracteres '#'

Este é o meu código até agora:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Counting{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int l = in.nextInt();
    int c = in.nextInt();
    Matrix m = new Matrix(l,c);
    m.ler(in); //ler matriz
    int valor = m.output(m);
    System.out.println(valor);

    }
}

class Matrix {
    char data[][]; //elementos da matriz
    int lin; //nr de linhas
    int col; //nr de colunas

    //construir matriz
    Matrix(int l, int c){
    data = new char[l][c];
    lin = l;
    col = c;
    }

    //ler Matriz

    public void ler(Scanner in){
    for(int i=0;i<lin;i++){
        String c = in.next();
        for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
        data[i][j] = c.charAt(j);
        }
    }
    }

    public int output(Matrix h){

    int linha=0;
    int coluna=0;
    int maior_tamanho=0;
    int maior_tamanhol=0;
    int maior_tamanhoc=0;

    for(int i=0;i<h.lin;i++){
         if(maior_tamanhol<=linha)
        maior_tamanho=linha;        
        linha=0;
        if(maior_tamanhoc<=coluna)
        maior_tamanhoc=coluna;

        coluna=0;    

        for(int j=0;j<h.col;j++){
        if(h.data[i][j]=='#'){
            linha++;

        }

        if(h.data[j][i]=='#'){
            coluna++;

        }
        }
    }
    if(maior_tamanhol>=maior_tamanhoc)
        maior_tamanho=maior_tamanhol;
    else
        maior_tamanho=maior_tamanhoc;

    return maior_tamanho;

    }


}
```

Para o input:

```
3 3
#..
##.
.#.
```

Ele dá o output certo, que é dois:

```
2
```

Mas com este input:

```
4 8
.....#..
##...#..
.#..###.
####.#..
```

Dá-me este erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at Matrix.output(Counting.java:67)
    at Counting.main(Counting.java:11)
```

Será que alguém me pode ajudar? Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você inverteu as variáveis `i` e `j` no seu método `output()`:

```
if(h.data[j][i]=='#'){
    coluna++;
}
```

O correcto é:

```
if(h.data[i][j]=='#'){
    coluna++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Já consegui resolver o problema, tendo pensado de uma maneira um pouco diferente:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Ex{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int l = in.nextInt();
        int c = in.nextInt();
        Matrix m = new Matrix(l,c);
        m.ler(in); //ler matriz

        int valor = m.output(m);
        System.out.println(valor);

    }
}

class Matrix {
    char data[][]; //elementos da matriz
    int lin; //nr de linhas
    int col; //nr de colunas

    //construir matriz
    Matrix(int l, int c){
        data = new char[l][c];
        lin = l;
        col = c;
    }

    //ler Matriz

    public void ler(Scanner in){
        for(int i=0;i<lin;i++){
            String c = in.next();
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
            data[i][j] = c.charAt(j);
            }
        }
    }

    public int output(Matrix h){


        int maior_tamanho=0;
        int maior_tamanhoh=0;
        int maior_tamanhov=0;

        //horizontal
        for(int i=0;i<h.lin;i++){
            int conta=0;
            for(int j=0;j<h.col;j++){
            while(data[i][j]=='#' && j<h.col){
                j++;
                conta++;
                if(j==h.col) break;
            }
            if(conta>maior_tamanhoh){
                maior_tamanhoh=conta;
        }

            conta=0;

            }
        }
        //vertical
        for(int i=0;i<h.col;i++){
            int conta=0;
            for(int j=0;j<h.lin;j++){
            while(data[j][i]=='#'){
                j++;
                conta++;
                if(j==h.lin) break;
            }
            if(conta>maior_tamanhov){
                maior_tamanhov=conta;

            }
        conta=0;

            }
        }

        if(maior_tamanhoh>=maior_tamanhov){
            maior_tamanho=maior_tamanhoh;

        }

        else{
            maior_tamanho=maior_tamanhov;

        }


        return maior_tamanho;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro uma abordagem diferente e mais linear, assumindo na mesma uma procura especifica para as linhas e para as colunas.

```
private int obterMaiorAtualizado(int repeticoes, int maior){
    return repeticoes > maior ? repeticoes: maior;
}

public int output(){
    int maiorLinhas = 0;
    int maiorColunas = 0;

    //linhas
    for(int i = 0;i < lin;i++) {
        int repeticoes = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
            if (data[i][j] == '#') {
                repeticoes++;
            }
            else {
                maiorLinhas = obterMaiorAtualizado(repeticoes, maiorLinhas);
                repeticoes = 0;
            }
        }
        maiorLinhas = obterMaiorAtualizado(repeticoes, maiorLinhas);
    }

    //colunas
    for(int i = 0;i < col; i++) {
        int repeticoes = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < lin; ++j) {
            if (data[j][i] == '#') {
                repeticoes++;
            }
            else {
                maiorColunas = obterMaiorAtualizado(repeticoes, maiorLinhas);
                repeticoes = 0;
            }
        }
        maiorColunas = obterMaiorAtualizado(repeticoes, maiorLinhas);
    }

    return Math.max(maiorLinhas, maiorColunas);
}
```

Repare que retirei o parâmetro de entrada `m` pois o método já é executado sobre a `Matrix`. Logo ficaria muito estranho chamar um método passando o próprio objeto como tinha no `Counting`:

```
int valor = m.output(m);
```

Assim torna-se mais natural fazendo apenas:

```
int valor = m.output();
```

[Veja a execução no Ideone](https://ideone.com/l3Qa4a)

Testes:

1. ```
   3 4
   ####
   ..#.
   ##..
   4
   ```
2. ```
   4 8
   .....#..
   ##...#..
   .#..###.
   ####.#..
   4
   ```
3. ```
   4 2
   #.
   #.
   #.
   ..
   3
   ```